# How to show the activity indicator in facebook integration through fbgraph api in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad

I am new to the iPhone Programming. I have integrated facebook into my application through fbgraph API. My intention is to show the activity indicator when facebook button clicked in my application.

Comment: you can also use sharekit for Facebook and twitter.......

Comment: But i must use FBgraph api for integrating the facebook into my application.is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection and UIActivityIndicatorView And NSData Objects in your **.H file.**

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest;
    NSURLConnection *theConnection;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator;
```

**.m File**

```
@synthesize youTubeWebView,receivedData,myIndicator;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{   
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [myIndicator startAnimating];
    myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
// Now your code of fb integration

NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url;    

    theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

    }

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
// code after Loading of fb page
    [myIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

Hope All this Helps You :))

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Where i have to put the activity indicator,In fbgraph supporting files,we dont have ViewDidload method.

Comment: See you can Show the Activity Indicator Till the Fb Page Start to appear. in connection did finish method before Stopping the Activity viewIndicator you code should upload the Fb url or that Permission request page. after that it is not in your Control. :)

Comment: Thank you.I have solved it by using the push Notification concept.

Comment: I have written the code in singleton class,in that I have implemented the code for facebook integration and implemented the push Notification concept after the friends list loaded.That's working for me.Thanks

Comment: Great.... Nice Idea but have you used Sharekit.??? As you have selected the answer.

Comment: Thank you.. No...with using fbgraph api only.I dont have any idea about using the sharekit...